# How to specify --jars in spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I want to add a couple of gcs connector jars to `spark-submit`. These will allow my spark application to read files from google storage.

I can do the following in python:

```
from pyspark import pandas as pd
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars","/usr/local/share/google/dataproc/lib/gcs-connector.jar,/usr/l
ocal/share/google/dataproc/lib/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.3.jar").getOrCreate()
pd.read_csv("gs://monsoon-credittech.appspot.com/mar19/training_data.csv",nrows=2)
```

But, I cannot achieve the same with `spark-submit` utility

```
spark-submit --master yarn --jars /usr/local/share/google/dataproc/lib/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.3.jar, /usr/local/share/google/dataproc/lib/gcs-connector.jar testing_dep.py --num 2 --path gs://monsoon-credittech.appsp
ot.com/mar19/training_data.csv
```

output:

```
2022-01-08 16:34:43,605 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: No main class set in JAR; please specify one with --class.
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.error(SparkSubmit.scala:972)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:492)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:898)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Why is the `spark-submit` asking me to provide `--class`. My entry point is testing_dep.py. I do not have `--class` to be specified. How can I achieve adding those jars?

Comment: Try removing the space between the comma and 2nd jar path. I think the second one is interpreted as your jar application.

Comment: @blackbishop, It's you!! saving my day yet again :). Yes, that was the issue. Thank you!